# Very slow wifi with new router

Tags: wifi, router

I recently changed my internet provider and switched from a Sagecom F@st 3890 router to a Hitron CGNV4. I use a Cisco Linksys wireless network adapter to connect to wifi on my [elementary OS](https://elementary.io/) 5.1 system (based on Ubuntu 18.04).

With the old Sagecom my connection speed was reasonable, but now it is extremely slow. I have 50 Mbps through lan, but I'm lucky to get 5 Mbps through wifi. Other devices (cells, tablets, TV) get around 30 Mbps through wifi.

Nothing changed except the router. What could be the reason for this and can it be fixed?

---

**Add 2**

Following the advice given [in this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462175/32411), I upgraded my kernel from the default 4.15 to a newer 4.20. It did not help.

---

**Add 1**

I came across this question [Wifi suddenly extremely slow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404287/wifi-suddenly-extremely-slow?rq=1) and tried the accepted answer. It did not help, but I noticed that my `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` file contains the following line:

```
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

<s>What does that mean? Is that supposed to be there?</s> (It is).

I tried modifying that file as stated in the answer, but nothing changed.

Comment: Did you use the same WIFI channel?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 2.4 Ghz because the wifi antenna apparently does not support 5 Ghz (at least it does not show)

Comment: the iwiwifi.conf just ensures that various related modules are removed when removing iwlwifi (or you'd get an error that it's used by an other module). You can ignore this for your problems.

Comment: @Mark I already did. As I said in the question, I get near 50 Mbps downloads with LAN.